# how to use payload using listadapter in android?

Tags: android

For updating the recyclerview item, I have used payload. Changing to use listadapter(extends recyclerview adapater), I realized I don't need to use notify. But there is a one question. I understand that notify method initialize the view, and for updating I have to use paload. So I did it like this

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads : List<Any>) {
                 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    (onClickListener as AudioItemClickListener).onClick(
                        listData[position],
                        holder
                    )
                    notifyItemChanged(position,"update")
                }
}
```

But at ListAdapter, I don't know how to use payload for updating view. Please let me the way